# Generate reCaptcha Token on submit

Tags: jquery, forms, recaptcha-v3

I'm trying to implement reCaptcha V3  on a form to generate the token only when the form is submitted:

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
/* intercept submit event */
$('#webQuery').submit(function(event) {
 grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('MYSITEKEY', {action: 'contact'}).then(function(token) {
    $('#recaptchaToken').val(token);
    });
});
 return true; 
}); 
</script>
```

FORM HTML:

```
<cfform method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="#page#" id="webQuery">
  <cfinput name="name" type="text">
  <cfinput type="hidden" id="recaptchaToken" name="rtoken">
  <cfinput type="submit" name="Submit">
</cfform>
```

The value generated by the token shows in the form field but not on the results page when the form processes.

Any idea how to actually post this value within the form?

Comment: You have to prevent the form submition first, than after getting the token and settings the value - than submit form.

Comment: Try something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/rL6fux5w/2/)